# Using eval in a function to replace a prefix on layer names?

Tags: javascript, function, coffeescript, eval

I need to write a function where I can pass it a string and it will replace the word "prefix" in it with the contents of that string. So every time I call the function and pass it a new string i.e. alpha, beta, etc it will completely rebuild all the layers and events inside, using that key as the prefix. I suspect I need to use eval, but I'm not really sure how in this case.

```
layoutViews = (prefix) ->
    prefix_layer1 = new Layer
        width: 100
        height: 100

    prefix_layer1.on Events.Click ->
        buttonActions()

layoutViews(alpha)
layoutViews(beta)
```

I'm using CoffeeScript, but any ideas in real JS are also welcome. I realize this specific question hints at my doing something else wrong in the project, but it's mostly for my own curiosity whether this is even possible.

Comment: Why do you need to generate dynamic variable names? How do you intend to reference these dynamic variables? Have you considered using an object to store data and use the keys as the reference points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want

```
function build(prefix) {
  window[prefix + "_hi"] = function() {
    alert("hi");
  };
}
```

Use like this:

```
build("test");
test_hi();
```

Window is just the global (! Bad) element in browsers, so you might consider to assign to `this` instead of `window` depends on your usage.

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Comment: @FuegoDeBassi No it does not. Do not use this, use an object instead.